# page load on master page

Tags: asp.net

I used a submit button. when I enter the logon details, full name should be displayed on master page. I could display the full name only when i refresh the browser. can you say hao to get rid of this event

Comment: `**turns on psychic debugging**` I'll get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If your code that displays full name on master page is in `Page_Load` event of master page then move it into  `Page_PreRender` event.